# React Router - How to prevent top level refresh when child component button is clicked, preventDefault does not seem to make a difference

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**Background:**

I have a simple react router:

```
<BrowserRouter >
    <Routes>
      <Route path="test/:locationId" element={<TestComponent />}></Route>
```

Then I have the component really simple:

```
function Inner(props) {
  let ele = JSON.stringify(props);

  console.log(" this is inner , with " + ele);

  const [value, setValue] = useState(parseInt(ele));

  return (
    <div onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
      <p> Inner component: {String(ele)}</p>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          console.log("inner btn clicked for " + value);
          setValue(value + 1);
        }}
      >
        {" "}
        inner btn with clicked value {value}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default function TestComponent(props) {
  console.log("TestComponent top level component " + new Date());
  console.log("I will do some heavy work like a big http request.....")
  const [res, setRes] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
  let params = useParams();
  console.dir(params);
  
  if (res.length > 0) {
    console.log("res > 0 ");
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {res.map((ele) => {
          return <div key={String(ele)}>{Inner(ele)}</div>;
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**Problem:**
Anytime I click on any of the 3 buttons, I see `TestComponent` refreshes from the top level, like a new line of `TestComponent top level component Mon Jul 18 2022 17:35:52 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`.

Now I plan to do some heavy http request and setState() inside `TestComponent`. However whenever I click on the buttons (in child components) this `TestComponent` always refreshes and thus will do the http request over and over again which I want to prevent. Tried e.stopPropagation() and e.preventDefault() but saw no difference.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHAN0.png)

Comment: Seems like you have a bug somewhere in the code you didn't show us that causes the parent to rerender. Nevertheless, it shouldn't matter, as you should make all fetch requests in `useEffect` hook to prevent refetching when the component rerenders.

Answer (score 2):

## Issues

It doesn't seem you understand the React component lifecycle well and are using the completely wrong tool to measure React renders.

1. All the console logs are occurring ***outside*** the render cycle as unintentional side-effects. What this means is that anytime React calls your app (*the entire app code*) to rerender (*for any reason*) that the component body is executed during the "render phase" in order to compute a diff for what changed and *actually* needs to be pushed to the DOM during the "commit phase". The commit phase is React rendering the app to the DOM and this is what we often refer colloquially as the React component rendering.

   [image]

   Note that the "render phase" is to be considered a pure function that can be called anytime React needs to call it. This is why it's pure function, i.e. without unintentional side-effects. The ***entire*** function body of a React function component ***is*** the "render" method.

   Note the "commit phase" is where the UI has been updated to the DOM and effects can now run.

   The issue of using the `console.log` *outside* the component lifecycle is exacerbated usually by the fact that we render our apps into the `React.StrictMode` component that does some double mounting of apps/components to [ensure reusable state](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#ensuring-reusable-state), and intentionally double invokes [certain methods and functions as a way to detect unintentional side-effects](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html#detecting-unexpected-side-effects).
2. `Inner` is defined like a React component but called manually like a regular function. This is a fairly obvious no-no. In React we pass a reference to our React components to React ***as JSX***. We don't ever directly call our React functions directly.

## Solution/Suggestion

- Move all the `console.log` statements into `useEffect` hooks so they are called ***exactly*** once per render (*to the DOM*) cycle. All *intentional* side-effects should be done from the `useEffect` hook.
- Render `Inner` as a React component and correctly pass props to it.

Example:

```
function Inner({ ele }) {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("this is inner , with " + ele);
  });

  const [value, setValue] = useState(ele);

  return (
    <div onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
      <p>Inner component: {String(ele)}</p>
      <button
        onClick={(e) => {
          e.preventDefault();
          e.stopPropagation();
          console.log("inner btn clicked for " + value);
          setValue(value + 1);
        }}
      >
        inner btn with clicked value {value}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

...

```
function TestComponent(props) {
  const [res, setRes] = useState([1, 2, 3]);
  let params = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("TestComponent top level component " + new Date());
    console.log("I will do some heavy work like a big http request.....");

    console.dir(params);

    if (res.length > 0) {
      console.log("res > 0 ");
    }
  });

  if (res.length > 0) {
    return (
      <div className="container">
        {res.map((ele) => (
          <div key={ele}>
            <Inner {...{ ele }} />
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="test/:locationId" element={<TestComponent />} />
</Routes>
```

[image]

Note that after the initial `StrictMode` mounting/remount that clicking the buttons only logs a single log from each `Inner` component.

[image: Edit react-router-how-to-prevent-top-level-refresh-when-child-component-button-is-c]